# Wordpress - Turn Pages into Posts and display Child of all Parents, whilst removing the Parent.

Tags: php, loops, wordpress-theming, wordpress

What I have:

- Home
- About

  - Projects

    - Project Pages 1

      - Project 1
    - Project Pages 2

      - Project 2
    - Project Pages 3

      - Project 3

I would like to loop through the Project Child Pages in order to display the pages in order of most recent of all sub-child projects then be able to echo or pull out Custom Fields ,

```
<?php the_title();?> 
<?php the_excerpt();?>
```

I do not want actually display the parent pages however, only for example project 1 or Project 2 or Project 3 etc.

Have tried many things but cannot seem to be able to do it with array_merge or wp_list_pages.

Any help would stop me from pulling my hair out. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do it. I used the following code. I hope it helps someone.

```
<?php
$args=array(
'post_type' => 'page',
'post__in' => array(345, 289),
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => 2,
'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);

if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

?>
```

This produced 2 posts as pages, from the specific category without displaying the parent, avoiding using `wp_list` but using a `new WP_Query` and `$args`. It worked as a temporary fix but does work.

Answer (score 0):

Read below URL i am very sure it is very help full to you.

**How to Exclude Posts from Children Categories on WordPress Category Page**

http://thesistut.com/2012/exclude-posts-from-children-category/